# Cant Launch Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Im still a newbie in anaconda, python and jupyter notebook. 
I am doing my assignment which is exploring anaconda and jupyter.

- windows 10, 64bit
- python 3.6.4
- anaconda 4.4.10

Why I cant launch jupyter notebook? First time i tried it was successful. And i continue with importing the libraries. Then, when the next time i open anaconda prompt and tried `jupyter notebook` , i got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2760, in get_entry_map
>       ep_map = self._ep_map
>     File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2731, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(attr)
>   AttributeError: _ep_map
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
>       return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)
>
> File "", line 2, in initialize
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1507, in initialize
>       self.init_webapp()
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1270, in init_webapp
>       self.jinja_environment_options
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 156, in **init**
>       default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 268, in init_settings
>       nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 973, in nbextensions_path
>       from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython__init__.py", line 55, in 
>       from .terminal.embed import embed
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 16, in 
>       from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 91, in 
>       class TerminalInteractiveShell(InteractiveShell):
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", line 134, in TerminalInteractiveShell
>       highlighting: \n %s""" % ', '.join(get_all_styles())
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\styles__init__.py", line 79, in get_all_styles
>       for name, _ in find_plugin_styles():
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\plugin.py", line 62, in find_plugin_styles
>       for entrypoint in iter_entry_points(STYLE_ENTRY_POINT):
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 737, in iter_entry_points
>       entries = dist.get_entry_map(group)
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2763, in get_entry_map
>       self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
>
> File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2496, in parse_map
>       raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
>   ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups

Is a big thank you if anyone can help me solve this! :)
Feel free to drop any comment/suggestion. Thank you!!

Comment: I think the best bet is to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall, but this time, [create](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) a conda environment and [activate](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) it before you launch jupyter so if this happens again, you can nuke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i recommend to **re install** anaconda again and to select the check box which says to **Set Anaconda path in system** so that you can use it from anywhere.

To make sure that we are going in right direction go to the **bin/** in the **anaconda** folder.

once you are in *bin* you can see that there is a **jupyter-notebook.exe** thus execute it in the command prompt.

Also you can try using **Anaconda Navigator** to do the same thing.

You can also try running it as *Administrator* if there are any permission issues.

**There have been changes in jupyter notebooks latest release so you can read the docs for more info**

Comment: i tried re install anaconda. there is no bin/ folder. and there is no anaconda prompt and anaconda navigator. T_T

Comment: Please check the **Anaconda** folder in *Program Data* or your *User* folder. Or simply use *Search* bar to find the folder.

Comment: is it the contents of anaconda folder shold be like this?


https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tof6EBnHx6T-zFQ-VJmbJAyW3yW9QgzH

Comment: i think there are some missing folders. i do reinstall many times. and during installation i got error message saying "failed to create menus" and during installation vs code it says something cant install due to unconnected to the internet, and have three option buttons, abort, retry and ignore

Comment: As you can see there is no **Scripts** folder which contains all the executables. Thus first clean your system by un-installing and removing any remaining folders manually and then follow the docs https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows which gives all the details. **Note that Install Microsoft VSCode is optional and installing it will require internet i guess.**

Comment: ok thank you. im done installed anaconda (finally) after i read through this website. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting#anaconda-installer-download-problems

but now i got the same error when to install vscode, saying that my laptop unconnected to the internet., and "unable to install vscode". is there any difference if i install or not install vscode?

Comment: well, my laptop is connected to the internet during the installation.

Comment: in the error box of "unable to install vscode", it also ask me to check 

C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\vscode_inst.py.log
C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\vscode_inst.log

so, here is the ss of the vscode_inst.py.log, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tof6EBnHx6T-zFQ-VJmbJAyW3yW9QgzH

Comment: Ok here is a way around : https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads download the setup and install manually then install anaconda without selecting VSCode option in installer. You have to manually run VScode every time and it wont be available in anaconda.

Comment: After you have installed VSCode from their site. you can launch it using .exe or from cmd its your choice. If this solves your problem then select the answer and close this thread.